# Display date, id column and other columns in Folium HeatMapWithTime

Tags: python, leaflet, gis, geopandas, folium

I have a taxi frequency dataset like this:

```
ID   Date         Latitude   Longitude   Sample_Mean
01   2019-10-09   40.431753  -3.711294   0.1
03   2019-10-21   40.431753  -3.711294   0.05
32   2020-03-22   40.458772  -3.699815   0.2
44   2020-03-29   40.431753  -3.711294   0.22
```

I am trying to create a heat map with time using folium to display the volume of taxi's on different days. I'm trying to do the following:

1. How to display the 'Date' as an index on the animation? [image: please see image]
2. How to display the 'ID' on each heat map spot?
3. How to display the 'Sample_Mean' on each heat map spot?

This is what I have tried:

```
# Make basemap
map = folium.Map(location=[25.41, -3.703], zoom_start=15, tiles='CartoDB positron')
df['date'] = df['date'].sort_values(ascending=True)
data = []
for _, d in df.groupby('date'):
    data.append([[row['latitude'], row['longitude'], row['Sample_Mean']] for _, row in d.iterrows()])

hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(data, auto_play=True,display_index=True,max_opacity=0.8)
hm.add_to(map)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that can be done with the heatmap animation in folium is to display the index as a date. As far as I know, it is not possible to display or annotate any other value. Instead, you can set the color distinction by threshold and the size of the circle radius. Here is an [example](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-101s-spatial-visualizations-and-analysis-in-python-with-folium-39730da2adf). See also the [official sample](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/HeatMapWithTime.ipynb).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
ID   date         latitude   longitude   Sample_Mean
01   2019-10-09   40.431753  -3.711294   0.1
03   2019-10-21   40.431753  -3.711294   0.2
04   2019-10-30   40.431753  -3.711294   0.8
32   2020-03-22   40.458772  -3.699815   0.4
44   2020-03-29   40.458772  -3.699815   0.66
45   2020-04-07   40.458772  -3.699815   0.95

'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['date'] = df['date'].sort_values(ascending=True)
data = []

for _, d in df.groupby('date'):
    data.append([[row['latitude'], row['longitude'], row['Sample_Mean']] for _, row in d.iterrows()])

import folium
import folium.plugins as plugins

m = folium.Map(location=[40.43, -3.703], zoom_start=13, tiles='CartoDB positron')
hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(data, auto_play=True,
                             display_index=True,
                             gradient={0.2: 'blue', 0.4: 'lime', 0.6: 'orange', 1: 'red'},
                             index=df['date'].tolist(),
                             max_opacity=0.8)
hm.add_to(m)

m
```

[image]