# time_slider_drag_update for TimestampedGeoJson not updating

Tags: python, plugins, jupyter-notebook, updates, folium

This is the data

```
    start = eartt1.pivot_table('id',
                          index = ['place', 'time_hour',
                                   'latitude',
                                   'longitude', 
                                   'mag'
                                   ],
                          columns = 'type',
                          aggfunc='count').reset_index()

start.head()
```

This is the function to create the features of the animation: time, location, icon

```
def create_geojson_features(df):
features = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    feature = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type':'Point', 
            'coordinates':[row['longitude'],row['latitude']]
        },
        'properties': {
            'time': pd.to_datetime(row['time_hh'], unit='h').__str__(),
            'style': {'color' : ''},
            'icon': 'circle',
            'iconstyle':{
                'fillColor': row['fillcolor'],
                'fillOpacity': 0.8,
                'stroke': 'true',
                'radius': row['mag']*10
            }
        }
    }
    features.append(feature)
return features
```

This initiates the Function

```
    start_geojson = create_geojson_features(start)
start_geojson[0]
```

start_geojson[0] displays the first date on 1970 that is suspicious as the dataset contains data from 1968

this creates animated map

```
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson


EQ_map = folium.Map(location = [2, -2],
                    tiles = "CartoDB Positron",
                    zoom_start = 2)


TimestampedGeoJson(start_geojson,
                  period = 'PT1H',
                  duration = 'PT1H',
                  transition_time = 1000,
                  auto_play = True).add_to(EQ_map)

EQ_map
```

time_slider_drag_update for  TimestampedGeoJson is not updating the different years when it goes through the data points. the data is from 1968 till 2021

Please help ;(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i0wZ.jpg)

You can find the entire notebook in here
https://nbviewer.org/github/panditadata/Earthquakes/blob/main/theone%20%281%29.ipynb#
or https://panditadata.com/theone_(3).html

Comment: I don't know if this is correct since you don't present any data, but what format is the time of the earthquake in the geojson properties? If it is in unix time, it needs to be converted.

Comment: Actually I discovered what is the real problem. My data to input into the timestampgeojson needs to be a list of lists … I’m not able to create a list of list from reading the data from a csv to a pandas data frame to a list of lists … I’m stuck there 

Comment: If you have user data and geojson, I may be able to help a little. can you provide a link to geojson and sample data?

Comment: [[[47.504539036025584, 4.292407029209247, 0.1],
  [47.69040904564529, 4.252424765823684, 0,2],
  ..]]] Data sample , please note than this is a list of lists and len(data) and len(data[0]) must be the same ( at least this is what happens in the example provided in plugins in GitHub)

Comment: Do you have data for your question? You commented that the data is already presented, where is it?

Comment: All the code used has been provided in the question, but I am sure Is because the data needs to be a list of lists and I’m not sure how to convert pandas data frame into list of lists having same length in both dimensions

Comment: [[[47.504539036025584, 4.292407029209247, 0.1], [47.69040904564529, 4.252424765823684, 0,2], ..]]] This is just small sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325958/heatmapwithtime-plugin-in-folium

This is similar question

Comment: Latitude, longitude, magnitude [[[47.504539036025584, 4.292407029209247, 0.1], [47.69040904564529, 4.252424765823684, 0,2], ..]]]

Comment: I think [my past responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889979/display-date-id-column-and-other-columns-in-folium-heatmapwithtime/67947734#67947734) will be helpful.

Comment: Definitely this will help me thanks a lot really you are the legend 